# Leaflet Multipolyline

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, leaflet

i want to use the addLatLng function to add a new point to my multipolyline. I am able to use the function with a normal single polyline, but with for example two lines, i don't know how i can access the second ring to add the new point.

I have tried some of those...

```
var polyline = L.polyline([[], []], {color: generateRandomColor()}).addTo(map);
var point = {lat: lat, lng: long};
 
var arr = polyline.getLatLngs();

polyline[1].addLatLng(point); //nope
polyline.addLatLng(arr[1], point); //nope
polyline.addLatLng(point) //yes but adds to the first polyline
```

I also can't understand the hint from the docs -

> addLatLng( latlng, <LatLng[]> latlngs?)
>
> Adds a given point to the polyline. By default, adds to the first ring of the polyline in case of a multi-polyline, but can be overridden by passing a specific ring as a LatLng array (that you can earlier access with getLatLngs).

Can you please give me an example in javascript code?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add the ring in the wrong order. Use following:

```
polyline.addLatLng(point, arr[1]); //yep
```